# JQuery - show multiple selected values dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple select dropdown. I am trying to show the selected values in the dropdown.

If I hard code the values, it works -

```
$("select[name=clause1]").val(["ab","cd"]);
```

but if I define a variable with the values, it does not -

```
var temp = "[\"ab\",\"cd\"]"; 
$("select[name=clause1]").val(temp);
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet sets the values using an array. Second tries it with just a string. Since there is no matching value of that string, it simply doesn't set the value of the select box.

Change your code to this instead:

```
var temp = ["ab", "cd"]; 
$("select[name=clause1]").val(temp);
```

Additionally, if you've the string (JSON), you can convert it to the array using `JSON.parse`:

```
var temp = JSON.parse("[\"ab\",\"cd\"]"); 
$("select[name=clause1]").val(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `eval` function for this purpose.

```js
var values= "[\"ab\",\"cd\"]"
$('select').val(eval(values))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
<option value="ab">ab</option>
<option value="bc">bc</option>
<option value="cd">cd</option>
</select>
```

However, [eval is evil](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) but worth useful in many cases. If you closely look into the link's description it will tell you the usage of `JSON.parse` using eval  but in a safer manner.